# SQL aggregate percentage for match predictions game

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm doing a predictions game and I have the following table

```
{MatchID, Team1Score, Team2Score}
```

How can I find out What's the percentage of the votes for team1 or team2?

I came up with the following:

```
SELECT        COUNT(dbo.Predictions.ID) AS Team1Wins, COUNT(Predictions_2.ID) AS 
Team1Loss, COUNT(Predictions_1.ID) AS Total
FROM            dbo.Predictions CROSS JOIN
                         dbo.Predictions AS Predictions_2 CROSS JOIN
                         dbo.Predictions AS Predictions_1
WHERE        (dbo.Predictions.Team1Score > dbo.Predictions.Team2Score) AND (Predictions_2.Team1Score < Predictions_2.Team2Score)
```

But I think there should be a way better way to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No instance in front of me just now so please forgive any typos

```
;with Winner as
(
select
    MatchID
   ,count(*) as number
   ,sum(case when Team1Score > Team2Score then 1 else 0) as Team1
   ,sum(case when Team1Score < Team2Score then 1 else 0) as Team2
   ,sum(case when Team1Score = Team2Score then 1 else 0) as Draw
from dbo.Predictions
group by MatchID
)
select
    MatchID
   ,Team1 * 100 / number as PercentTeam1
   ,Team2 * 100 / number as PercentTeam2
   ,Draw * 100 / number as PercentDraw
from Winner
order by MatchID;
```

HTH